# adding spacing in css vertical menu

Tags: html, css

I want more space in between each menu name, i don;t want them so close together, How can I manage this? they are directly under each other, near touching, what would be best way to add space?

here's my CSS

```
#navside ul
{
margin: 2;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navside ul li { display: block; }

#navside ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 1em 1em;
color: #bfaeae;

}
#navside ul li a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #f0f0f0;

}
```

and here is my menu

```
<div id="navside">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="#">menu one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu one</a></li>
   </ul>




        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
#navside li{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vq3ea2e/

Comment: ok thanks, that worked. and does my code look messy or does it look fine?